# MySQL: Large data slow reads

Tags: mysql

I have very large table with 17,044,833 Rows and 6.4 GB in size. I am running the simple query below and it takes like 5 seconds. Any ideas what optimizations can I do to improve the speed of this query?

```
SELECT 
`stat_date`,
SUM(`adserver_impr`),
SUM(`adserver_clicks`)
FROM `dfp_stats` WHERE 
`stat_date` >= '2014-02-01' 
AND 
`stat_date` <= '2014-02-28'
```

MySQL Config:

```
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
```

Server:

```
Memory: 48GB     
Disk: 480GB
```

**UPDATE**

ORIGINAL QUERY:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
DS.`stat_date` 'DATE',
DC.`name` COUNTRY,
DA.`name` ADVERTISER,
DOX.`id` ORDID,
DOX.`name` ORDNAME,
DLI.`id` LIID,
DLI.`name` LINAME,
DLI.`is_ron` ISRON,
DOX.`is_direct` ISDIRECT,
DSZ.`size` LISIZE,
PUBSITE.`id` SITEID,

SUM(DS.`adserver_impr`) 'DFPIMPR',
SUM(DS.`adserver_clicks`) 'DFPCLCKS',
SUM(DS.`adserver_rev`) 'DFPREV'

FROM `dfp_stats` DS
LEFT JOIN `dfp_adunit1` AD1 ON AD1.`id` = DS.`dfp_adunit1_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_adunit2` AD2 ON AD2.`id` = DS.`dfp_adunit2_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_adunit3` AD3 ON AD3.`id` = DS.`dfp_adunit3_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_orders` DOX  ON DOX.`id` = DS.`dfp_order_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_advertisers` DA  ON DA.`id` = DOX.`dfp_advertiser_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_lineitems` DLI  ON DLI.`id` = DS.`dfp_lineitem_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_countries` DC  ON DC.`id` = DS.`dfp_country_id`
LEFT JOIN `dfp_creativesize` DSZ ON DSZ.`id` =  DS.`dfp_creativesize_id`
LEFT JOIN `pubsites` PUBSITE
ON AD1.`pubsite_id` = PUBSITE.`id`
OR AD2.`pubsite_id` = PUBSITE.`id`

WHERE
DS.`stat_date` >= '2014-02-01'
AND DS.`stat_date` <= '2014-02-28'
AND PUBSITE.`id` = 6
GROUP BY  DLI.`id`,DS.`stat_date`;
```

RESULTS OF EXPLAIN:   (This is after adding the COVERING INDEX)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhVeB.png

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't, you might want to index the `stat_date` field for faster lookups. Here's the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD INDEX (COLUMN_NAME);
```

Read more about indexing and optimizations here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

For best performance of this query, create a covering index:

```
... ON `dfp_stats` (`stat_date`,`adserver_impr`,`adserver_clicks`)
```

The output from EXPLAIN should show "Using index". This means that the query can be satisfied entirely from the index, without needing to visit any pages in the underlying table. (The term "covering index" refers to an index that includes all of the columns referenced by a query.)

At a minimum, you'll want an index with a leading column of `stat_date` so that the query can use an index range scan operation. An index range scan can essentially skip over boatloads of rows, and more quickly locate the rows that actually need to be checked.

As far as changes to the configuration of the MySQL instance, that really depends on whether the table is InnoDB or MyISAM.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

For InnoDB, memory is still king. If there's memory available on the server, then you can increase innodb_buffer_pool.

Also consider enabling the MySQL query cache. (We have the query cache enabled only for queries that are specifically enabled to use the cache with the SQL_CACHE keyword i.e. `SELECT SQL_CACHE t.foo,`, so we don't clutter up the cache with queries that don't give us benefit. For other queries, we avoid running the extra code (that would otherwise be required) to search the cache and maintain the cache contents.

The place we get a benefit from the query cache is from "expensive" queries (which look at a lot of rows and do a lot of joins) against tables that are relatively static, and that return small resultsets.  (I'd consider a query that gets a single row with a SUMs from a whole boatload of rows would be a good candidate for the query cache, if the table is infrequently updated, or if the same query is going to be run several times before a DML operation on the table invalidates the cache.)

---

It's a bit odd that your query is returning a non-aggregate that isn't in a GROUP BY clause.

If your query is using an index on stat_date, it's likely the query is returning the lowest value of `stat_date` within the range specified by the predicate; so it's likely that you would get an equivalent result using `SELECT MIN(stat_date) AS stat_date`.

---

A more complicated approach would be to setup a "summary" table, and refresh that periodically with the results from a query, and then have the application query the summary table. (A data warehouse type approach.)  This doesn't work if you need "up-to-the-minute" accuracy. To get that, you'd likely need to introduce triggers on the target table, to maintain the summary table on INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations.

If I went that route, I'd probably opt for storing a summary row for each `stat_date`, so it could accommodate queries on any range or set of dates...

```
CREATE TABLE dfp_stats_summary 
( stat_date       DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, adserver_impr   BIGINT
, adserver_clicks BIGINT
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

-- refresh
INSERT INTO dfp_stats_summary (stat_date, adserver_impr, adserver_clicks)
SELECT t.stat_date
     , SUM(t.adserver_impr) AS adserver_impr
     , SUM(t.adserver_clicks) AS adserver_clicks
  FROM dfp_stats
 GROUP BY t.stat_date
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
       UPDATE adserver_impr = VALUES(adserver_impr)
           , adserver_clicks = VALUES(adserver_clicks)
 ;
```

The refresh query will crank; you might want to specify a date range in a WHERE clause to do a month or two at a time, and loop through all the possible months.

With the summary table populated, just change the original query to reference the new summary table, rather than the detail table. It would be a lot faster to add up 28 summary rows than several hundred thousands detail rows.

---

Comment: I will try to create a covering index. I already have an index on stat_date. The tables are all InnoDB.

Comment: @iser2884319: NOTE: If you create a multi-column index with `stat_date` as the leading column, then the other index on just the single `stat_date` column won't be needed (unless it's being used to enforce a unique constraint.)

Comment: so basically you are saying is try the EXPLAIN to say Using Index? So if I add more columns to my query the I will have to include it in my covering indexes, correct?

Comment: @user2884319: yes, basically. There's obviously going to be a tipping point. By storing a subset, we're getting more rows packed into a page (fewer page accesses) PLUS we don't have to follow the index pointer to access a page in the underlying table. Getting the values we need straight from the index is a shorter code path. Yes, when MySQL uses a "covering index", the EXPLAIN output will show "Using index" in the extra column. And, if your query was doing a `GROUP BY stat_date`, MySQL can use that same index to avoid a "Using filesort" operation.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I added the covering index. I know it is confusing that I am not doing any Group by and stuff. I just added the original query with all the joins. It doesn't have any index on the second row (DS). I am still trying to get it using indexes but if you have any ideas that would be awesome.

Comment: The index is a covering index for the first query, but not for the query you added to the question. That second query references seven additional columns from DS; MySQL can't optimize the `GROUP BY` using the index, because the `GROUP BY` is on other columns, not just `stat_date`, and because the SUM() aggregates from DS can potentially be "doubled" because matching rows from both AD1 and AD2 could potentially have a matching row from PUBSITE.

Comment: It's odd that you are doing a GROUP BY on just dfp_lineitem_id and stat_date, but you are also including non-aggregates like `DC.name`, which is going to pick up a value from just one row in DS, even though there could be several different values. (Other RDBMS would throw an exception, MySQL is more lenient about that.) I'm not sure the query is even returning the resultset you are expecting it to return.